# Get-Content not in parentheses - process access denied

Tags: powershell

When using `Get-Content` to remove white space from a file:

```
$file = "C:\Folder\MyFile001.txt"
Get-Content -Path $file | ? { -not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) } | Set-Content -Path $file
```

Shows the error message 'Set-Content : The process cannot access the file '...' because it is being used by another process.

The fix is to use parentheses with `Get-Content`:

```
(Get-Content -Path $file) | ...
```

What is the reason for this? I would like to understand what difference the parentheses make and if this applies to other cmdlets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parentheses work in Powershell like they do in Algebra.

Kind of.

PowerShell executes the command in parentheses first, and then attempts to type-match it to wherever it's going. In this case, you're telling it to finish running Get-Content and reading the buffer into memory before it moves on to the next command, rather than streaming everything through the pipe.

This is similar to how BaSH works, where you use something like (assuming "service.txt" contains a single line that says apache):

```
Service $(cat /etc/service.txt) Stop
>> Service apache stop
```

Which will execute the command in $() and return it as text before running the rest of the command.

In PowerShell, you can use the parentheses' type matching power to do neat things like make it return only a single object property:

```
(Get-ChildItem -filter "*.pdf" -Path .\Projects).FullName 
>> C:\Users\ncf\Projects\Documentation.pdf
```

Answer (score 4):

When a cmdlet outputs something on the pipeline, the pipeline is executed before the next output of the cmdlet is processed. So as your string works its way down the pipeline to `Set-Content`, `Get-Content` is still active (with the output file open) waiting for its turn to continue execution. However, when you wrap the expression in `()`, all the output is gathered into an array, which is then pushed down the pipeline. `Get-Content` is done and the file is closed. To demonstrate, consider this function:

```
function get-10dates { $count = 0; while($count -lt 10){ get-date; $count += 1 }}
```

when you run it and pipe it to a `foreach` loop:

```
get-10dates | foreach { $_; sleep -Seconds 1 }
```

you get the following output, with each date delayed by a second, due to the `sleep` in the foreach:

```
# ~> get-10dates | foreach { $_; sleep -Seconds 1 }

June 19, 2019 9:58:36 AM
June 19, 2019 9:58:37 AM
June 19, 2019 9:58:38 AM
June 19, 2019 9:58:39 AM
June 19, 2019 9:58:40 AM
June 19, 2019 9:58:41 AM
June 19, 2019 9:58:42 AM
June 19, 2019 9:58:43 AM
June 19, 2019 9:58:44 AM
June 19, 2019 9:58:45 AM
```

Now if you wrap the function in `()`. you can see that all 10 dates are created at once (within 1 second), before they are passed down the pipeline:

```
# ~> (get-10dates) | foreach { $_; sleep -Seconds 1 }

June 19, 2019 9:58:53 AM
June 19, 2019 9:58:53 AM
June 19, 2019 9:58:53 AM
June 19, 2019 9:58:53 AM
June 19, 2019 9:58:53 AM
June 19, 2019 9:58:53 AM
June 19, 2019 9:58:53 AM
June 19, 2019 9:58:53 AM
June 19, 2019 9:58:53 AM
June 19, 2019 9:58:53 AM
```