# What does the parenthesis do in this PowerShell command?

Tags: powershell, pipe

Why adding parenthesis suppressed the error?

```
PS D:\logs> Get-Content .\cluster.log -Encoding Unicode | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 -Path .\cluster.log
Set-Content : The process cannot access the file 'D:\logs\cluster.log' because it is being used by another process.
At line:1 char:58
+ ... g Unicode | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 -Path .\cluster.log ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-Content], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand

PS D:\logs> (Get-Content .\cluster.log -Encoding Unicode) | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 -Path .\cluster.log
PS D:\logs>
```

Comment: As `Get-Content` and `Set-Content` are part of the same pipeline, they try to open the file at the beginning of the pipeline. As `Get-Content` opens the file first without enabling write sharing, `Set-Content` can't open it. The parentheses make it so that `Get-Content` runs in a sub pipeline, whose output is collected in its entirety. Now `Set-Content` can open the file again as it is already closed.

Comment: Wow, interesting! This is exactly the same as in Bash. Do you mind paste your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: This should be closed as duplicate instead. [Get-Content not in parentheses - process access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56672253/get-content-not-in-parentheses-process-access-denied)

Answer (score 1):

As `Get-Content` and `Set-Content` are part of the same pipeline, they try to open the file at the beginning of the pipeline. As `Get-Content` opens the file first without enabling write sharing, `Set-Content` can't open it. The parentheses make it so that `Get-Content` runs in a sub pipeline, whose output is collected in its entirety. Now `Set-Content` can open the file again as it is already closed.